# How to add a color effect to UI element in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, effect

I want to add a color effect to a UI element in python's tkinter GUI toolkit. I am using the `PhotoImage` class.

I tried searching for ways all over the Internet, but no luck. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What kind of color effect do you want to add?

Comment: @martineau I want to set the color effect to a hexadecimal color value.

Comment: In tkinter you can set color values in hexadecimal by using strings like `'#fe08c1'` where each pair of digits correspond to an 8-bit RGB values in that order. These can be used anywhere a color value can be specified when creating widgets, like a red `Button` with a green text label.

Comment: @martineau What if I wanted a color change for a gif image?

Comment: You would need to use some other module like `PIL` (Python Image Library) to modify images. Afterwards the modified image could then be used by `tkinter` like any other.